# Python: approximate the integration over a region with finite number of points

Tags: python

I have a set of 2D array of mesh grid points that covers the rectangular region. (-100,100)x(-100,100)

```
>>> x # shape is (4000000, 2)
>>> array([[-100. , -100. ],
           [ -99.9, -100. ],
           [ -99.8, -100. ],
           ...,
           [  99.7,   99.9],
           [  99.8,   99.9],
           [  99.9,   99.9]])
```

I have a function R^2 -> R such that can be evaluated over all theses points; however, I don't have analytic form of my function (you can think it as a neural network, can evaluate on any points on this mesh grid rectangular )

```
>>> f_x # the evaluation on pts; and its shape is (4000000,)
>>> array([-1.34405857e+47, -1.34137180e+47, -1.33868771e+47, ...,
       -5.54445000e+02, -5.54445000e+02, -5.54445000e+02])
```

Now; I want to integrate my function over any of the subregion (let's say (-20,20)x(-20,20) ). Since my f_x supposed to be a valid normalized distribution with most of mass in this region, the integral over such region should be close to one

How do I do this efficiently in python? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) looks to be what you need:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
integration = quad(array, -20, 20)
delta_from_one = 1 - integration
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: thanks for the reply; but I thought `quad` takes the argument function. But in my case, I don't have the closed form of my function; I only have its evaluation over the region

Comment: Did you try it out or are you just speculating? There are a number of tests in scipy that seem to imply that you can integrate based on numerical arrays.

Comment: I tried to pass an array into it; it gives me `ValueError: invalid callable given`; it requires the argument to be callable

Comment: anyway; I decided to use the integral definition by dividing rectangular to numerically compute